# How to pass a logical R object to a data block in a Stan file

Tags: rstan

If a list of data includes a logical variable `x`, namely, `x=TRUE` or `x=FALSE`. 
Then how to　declare such a variable in a Stan file?

For example, if an R object `x` is an integer, then

```
data{

int <lower=0>x;

}
```

I want to know its  logical version. I guess

```
data{

               bool x;

    }
```

### and it does not work as following;

```
SYNTAX ERROR, MESSAGE(S) FROM PARSER:
 error in 'foo' at line 16, column 0
  -------------------------------------------------
    14:   
    15: 
    16: bool x;
       ^
    17: 
  -------------------------------------------------

PARSER EXPECTED: <one of the following:
  a variable declaration, beginning with type,
      (int, real, vector, row_vector, matrix, unit_vector,
       simplex, ordered, positive_ordered,
       corr_matrix, cov_matrix,
       cholesky_corr, cholesky_cov
  or '}' to close variable declarations>
Error in stanc(filename, allow_undefined = TRUE) : 
  failed to parse Stan model 'foo' due to the above error.
```

Comment: And what happens when you try your guess?

Comment: It does not work., I add the error.

Comment: To show what you have tried please add a [mre] that produces the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe logicals are resolved to their integer values of 0L for FALSE and 1L for TRUE, so using int is appropriate.

Comment: Thank you, in a stan file, it is not required the `L` to coerce real to  integer. I understand that `TRUE` in R corresponds to `1` in C++ and `FALSE` in R is  associated `0` in C++. Thank you

Comment: Stan resolves R's TRUE and FALSE to 0 or 1 when used as data inputs in RStan.  In R, typing's considerably trickier because it's dynamic and implicit, but logicals when used like numbers, will also be interpreted as 0 and 1 in R.

Answer (score 2):

Stan does not have a proper boolean type.  Like C and C++, we use integer value 0 to denote false and value 1 to denote true.  To implement a boolean type in Stan, declare it as an integer with a lower bound of 0 (false) and upper bound of 1 (true).

```
int<lower = 0, upper = 1> c;
```

R distinguishes integer types from logical types, but allows a lot of conversion.  For example, if we define `b` to be the result of comparing 1 with itself, its value is `TRUE` and its type is logical (`logi` in R):

```
> b = (1 == 1)

> b
[1] TRUE

> str(b)
 logi TRUE
```

So if I write this Stan program whose behavior differs on a passed boolean,

```
data {
  int<lower = 0, upper = 1> b;
}
parameters {
  real y;
}
model {
  if (b)
    y ~ normal(0, 1);
  else
    y ~ normal(10, 10);
}
```

RStan is happy to coerce the boolean, so it's OK to have

```
fit <- sampling(model, data = list(b = b))
```

where the value `b` is a `logi` type in R.

Comment: I'm glad to hear from you because your the one of the author!! Thank you for the clear explanation.

Comment: I am one of the developers of Stan, but I work on the low level C++ and the language.  I'm just a user of rstan like everybody else.